# Graph API retrieve Sharepoint list with lookup field values

Tags: sharepoint, graph

I have a Sharepoint list **Region** with a value that is a lookup field **Markets** that references **Markets** list.

I'm able to filter by the lookup ID:

https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx/lists/REGION/items?expand=fields(select=PVRegion,Markets)&filter=fields/MarketsLookupId eq 1

But I want to get some fields from **Markets** list with this lookup attribute, as PVOps, LinkTitle, ...

Is it possible to get this with only one query? Or I need to query **Markets** list with the LookupId?

Comment: You need to execute a new query for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately you'll need a separate query to get those values.  This is particularly frustrating when dealing with users since you only get the ID of the given user as it appears in the UserInformation list.